# Determining if script was called directly with NodeJS Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

How do you know if a script was called directly with NodeJS modules? (i.e. where the `package.json` specifies `"type": "module"`)

For example, you might have two files, `script1.js` and `script2.js` We may use some utilities of `script1.js` in `script2.js`, but we don't want `script1.js` to execute when importing it.

```js
// script1.js
export const func = () => "A reusable function's output"

// TODO if executed with "node script1.js" execute this:
console.log("I did an operation: " + func())
```

```js
// script2.js
import { func } from "./script1.js"

// There shouldn't be any output because script1 wasn't called directly!
```

In previous versions of NodeJS (commonjs style) you could use `if (!module.parent) { /* ... */ }`, but module is not defined when using NodeJS with `"type": "module"`

Comment: In one line (ES6): import { fileURLToPath } from "url"; const directlyCalled = process.argv[process.argv.length-1] === fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could examine:

`process.argv[1]` and it will be the path to the script that nodejs was launched with.

In the doc, they show an example where a command line of:

```
$ node process-args.js
```

Will show this for `process.argv[1]`:

```
/Users/mjr/work/node/process-args.js
```

If you parse the filename off that, then you can compare it to your own module's filename.

```
 import path from 'path';

 function getLaunchFile() {
     return path.basename(process.argv[1]);
 }

 if (getLaunchFile() === "script1.js") {
     // I am the main launch file
 }
```

And, if you want to dynamically get the current module's filename, you can use this:

Which would let you make this:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

function isLaunchFile() {
    const launchFile = process.argv[1];
    const moduleFile = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
    return moduleFile === launchFile;
}
```

Comment: thanks @jfriend00, I've packaged this up into an npm module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-launch-file to make it easier for others.

Comment: @seveibar - Perhaps you figured this out already, but there was a mistake in the second version where it was comparing base filename to full path and thus never matching.  I've fixed it.  Also, notice the second version compares full paths and thus a common name like "index.js" will never conflict.  A common filename could give a false positive in the first version.

Comment: yes I corrected that in the library (thanks for improving the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, I've packaged the method by @jfriend00 into a library called [is-launch-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-launch-file)

```js
import isLaunchFile from "is-launch-file"
 
if (isLaunchFile(import.meta.url)) {
    // This file was called directly.
}
```

All credit goes to @jfriend00 for the vanilla solution.

Comment: This is the reason for npm dependency hell.

Comment: consider that for some applications _each file_ may contain a launch script that needs execution. In my case, this function would have been reused 5 times. Rather than document this function as part of my repository and increase knowledge burden for maintainers, I've isolated it into a package with documentation and tests.

Comment: I know, this is arguable. Every JS project I have been involved in so far suffered from deprecated sub-sub-sub-dependencies with no-brainer functionality after a few months. For my taste, the lifecycle management burden of an external dependency does not outweigh the knowledge burden concerning a function with 3 lines of code.

Comment: I'm not sure what the right criteria for minimizing application dependencies is. From my work it depends on size (but this package is too small to be a burden). I'm not sure I buy the argument that it decreases maintenance cost (less code in my project, less to worry about, even if the imported packages require an audit). More complex dependencies for frameworks do cause code rot, e.g. Angular 1.x would put code in the "this should probably be completely rewritten" bucket.

Maybe "this is a pattern that JS developers should know" is plausible, but this operation isn't that common.

Comment: One line alternative (ES6): import { fileURLToPath } from "url"; const directlyCalled = process.argv[process.argv.length-1] === fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);